# Python format combined with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, format

This is code I'm trying to get working. I want pass parameter to `get_jquery` function:

```
def get_jquery(wid):
    """
    Gets JavaScript code.
    :return: JavaScript code.
    """
    return """
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".simple_field").hide()
      $("input[name='status']").change(function(){
        if($("#secure_message").prop("checked")){ 
          $("#login").attr("action", "/link/webpage.php?wid={wid}")
          $(".sender_field").show()
          $(".simple_field").hide()
        }
        else{
          $("#login").attr("action", "/link/webpage.php?wid={wid}")
          $(".sender_field").hide()
          $(".simple_field").show()
          
        }
        alert($("#login").attr("action"));
      });
    }); 
    """.format(wid=wid)
```

When attempt to pass some wid value, to function, I'm getting, this error:

> KeyError: '\n      $("'
> 2017-09-15 13:05:36,602 ERROR: '\n      $("'

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: You can't go with format here, because it recognizes {\n $(".simple_field....} as a key to substitude. Use string concatenation for this.

Comment: Or don't do this at all. Use a template.

Comment: `""" one  """ + """ element """ `  concatenation works, thanks. How to use template in this example?